Chart.js: Aligning multiple side-by-side bar charts with inconsistent label widths
I'm using Chart.js (4.4) to create multiple bar charts side by side, each representing a different country. My current implementation uses separate <canvas> elements for each chart. However, I'm encountering an issue where the leftmost chart is smaller than the others due to its y-axis labels taking up more space, and the labels are getting cut off since they are quite long. How can I make the labels show fully and make sure that all of the bars are aligned?
My current attempt
Here is my current implementation:
COUNTRIES.map((country, index) => {
  return (
    <BarChart
      showLabel={index === 0}
      data={{
        labels: labels,   // Prizes and awards
        datasets: [
          {
            label: country,
            data: data[index],
          },
        ]

      }}
      width={100}
      height={300} />
  )
})

with the only notable chart options being indexAxis: 'y'

I managed to find a sample stacked floating bar chart example that didn't need  separate canvas elements to display each set of data.
https://codepen.io/elizzk/pen/oNvdbgN?editors=0010


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
